# Shifter is floating and cant go into gear

Tags: transmission, mitsubishi

so im having a problem with my 93 mitsubishi colt. So i started the car and before it was sitting for abou 3 days and when i drove for about 2 minutes than i sopped put car into neutral, put the handbrake on and when i got back in the car to  drive the shifter was broken and it was just freely moving around and i couldint get it into gear. i didint smell burnt cluth so im wondering what could be the problem. whould be very thankful for some help :)

Answer (score 1):

look in the engine bay for where the shift linkages hook onto the transmission. If they dont appear to be broken (there is 2 one for up-down one for left-right) have someone move the stick shift. If the cables move the problem is somewhere in the transmission if not the problem is between the linkage and the shifter